# A discussion about optimal DB design for saving aggregations

Tags: database-design, aggregate

- I have raw data.
- There are 4 filters defined on this raw data: `f1...f4`.
- There are 50k~ permutations of `f1...f4` filters.
- There are 2000~ time windows. Each time window is 1 hour.
- For each time window, for each filter permutation, 50 different aggregations are saved.
- I think of saving this data in a single aggs table, with a schema as follows:

`f1 | ... | f4 | agg1 | ... | agg50 | start_time | end_time`

- That means the table will hold 50k * 2k = 100m~ rows, and more.
- When I query the data, in 100% of the time I will filter `f1..f3`.
- Most of the queries are performing some aggregation on top of some agg column.

i.e, `select count(agg1) where user_id=... f1..f4=... agg1=... start_time=...`

- Filter `f4` and timestamps (`start/end_date`) are optional for filtering.
- That means the query is running on a pretty "small" number of rows.
- Some queries will update some rows and backfill missing ones.

1. I assume I need to index the table by `f1..f3` at least. Should I partition it also in some way?
2. Should I use time-series DB? Are there any benefits in this compared to "raw" Postgres?
3. This table will hold a lot of data. I assume it might reach 200m rows. I assume this will deteriorate the performance of the DB. What solutions I may apply to keep the querying fast? Retention? Compression?

Maybe the whole DB design should be different. Please express your general opinion on it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli
I thought I did it. Can you tell me what problems there are with what I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume I need to index the table by f1..f3 at least.

Yes, probably an index on `(f1, f2, f3, f4, start_time, end_time)` or `(f1, f2, f3, start_time, end_time, f4)` would be ideal, depending on if your queries have predicates for `f4` more often or `start_time` and `end_time`. Testing and comparing query plans is the best way to determine which index is most optimal.

> Should I partition it also in some way?

Not likely, partitioning is not really meant to improve DQL query performance, as it's a linear search time algorithm. Proper indexes generally prevail with performance because they use a logarithmic algorithm, a B-Tree, which is literally exponentially better than partitioning.

> This table will hold a lot of data. I assume it might reach 200m rows. I assume this will deteriorate the performance of the DB. What solutions I may apply to keep the querying fast? Retention? Compression?

No need to make that assumption, as previously mentioned, B-Tree indexes have a search time of `O(log(n))`. Depending on the fan-out factor, if we assumed base-2, in the worst case `log2(100 million)` is only 27 nodes in the index that need to be searched through to find your data. If your table grew to 1 billion records, then `log2(1 billion)` is only 30 nodes that would need to be searched through, at most. Modern databases typically do better than this, based on the fan-out, and I only used base-2 as a generalization for demonstration. Very easy for any modern computer (even your cellphone) to handle.

200 million rows isn't that huge. Retention is up to you, if it makes logical sense, but generally isn't necessary as first line of defense for DQL query performance. I've worked with tables in the 10s of billions of rows on modest hardware, and proper indexing was all that was needed for the queries to return in under a second to a few seconds max.

Comment: I aim for sub-second queries for all `select`s (similar to the example above).
Your comment has a lot of information and is very informative.
I've just read this amazon article: shorturl.at/hnQV0
And I feel like it a bit contradicts the things you said.
It advocates BRIN indexing and time partitioning on the data.
It shows how it affects both the size and performance of the database.
I can generally consider my use case as a "time series", as it is dependent mostly on queries on time.
What do you think?

Comment: @igalleikin Never used a time series database implementation, as I never needed one, even when working with 10s of billions of records (which was financial data and ergo valid as of only a certain time period). The article you linked is all about time series database optimization so I wouldn't expect it to necessarily apply to what I said, which is about general purpose database use. Even BRIN indexes are something I've never needed to use but there are probably granular specific cases where that's the better choice than a B-Tree index, which is why I talk about proper indexing in general.

Comment: Either way, proper indexing, even just B-Tree indexes alone will carry you far. The examples I mentioned where my queries were up to a few seconds long were because of the amount of data being returned to the client consumer (millions to 100s of millions of rows), and not the actual lookup time via the B-Tree index which took milliseconds, even against 10s of billions of rows. My understanding is you're never actually returning a lot of data to the client at one time, so I don't see why a regular B-Tree index (when properly defined) wouldn't also result in your queries being 10s of ms too.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @igalleikin No prob! If you think of any other questions feel free. Also feel free to upvote and / or accept this answer if you found it helpful so others with similar questions also find it too.